# Socket.io How to properly handle client reconnection on a server side

Tags: socket.io

I have a mobile app which may loose a connection with a server, for instance a network switched from 4g to wifi.
In this case it tries 3 times to reconnect with a server. And it usually succeeds.
But right now my server always fires the event disconnect and deletes user even if he reconnected.

Right my server side code looks like this:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    deleteUser();
});
```

What I want is if user successfully reconnected, do not delete it.
In other words:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    if (user reconnected after n reconnection tries) return; // do not delete 

    deleteUser(); // user didn't reconnect after n tries, delete him.
});
```

But I don't know how to implement this logic on a server.
Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

[According to the Socket.IO documentation](https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-socket-instance/#events), the `reconnect` event is emitted only on the client side and not on the server side. Therefore, it is not possible to detect a reconnection event and perform actions from the server. However, on Socket.IO version `4.6.0` and upwards, you can use the [**Connection State Recovery** feature](https://socket.io/docs/v4/connection-state-recovery).

Furthermore, you could track the disconnected sessions by storing their Socket IDs in an array and then on every connection, for a specific period of time, check if the client is recovered. If they're in a connected and recovered state, don't delete the user from the Database. If they're not, delete the user from the Database. Here's an example of how you could do it.

```
/* Create Required Functions and Variables */
let lostClients = {};
const newUser = (socket_id) => {};
const deleteUser = (socket_id) => {};

/* Define the Socket.IO Object */
const io = new Server(httpServer, {
  connectionStateRecovery: {
    maxDisconnectionDuration: 2 * 60 * 1000, // the backup duration of the sessions and the packets
    skipMiddlewares: true, // whether to skip middlewares upon successful recovery
  }
});

/* Socket on Connection Event */
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  if (socket.recovered) {
    /* Recovery was successful, Remove the Client from lostClients */
    delete lostClients[socket.id];
  } else {
    /* New, Unrecoverable Session */
    newUser(socket.id);

    /* Purge lostClients */
    Object.keys(lostClients).forEach((client) => {
        if (lostClients[client] < 1) delete lostClients[client];
        lostClients[client]--;
    });
  }

  /* Socket on Disconnect Event */
  socket.on("disconnect", (reason) => {
      /* Since we aren't sure if a reconnect would work, we'll add the user to the lostClients object */
      lostClients[socket.id] = 5; // Try 5 attempts till purged
  });
});
```

You could write similar code, combining the Connection State Recovery feature, a Disconnected Clients Objects, the `onConnect` and `socket.recovered` APIs to approach the reconnection and make the app work as intended.

Comment: As far as I know socket.io.on("reconnect" - is the client side only code. Server side doesn't have something like Manager or reconnect event. I also red documentation. It doesn't give an answer how to manage reconnect logic on a server side. That's why I ask my question here.

Comment: Yeah you're correct. I misread the documentation. Thanks for letting me know. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the response. At least I have something to think about. I'm not quite sure about server 4.6.0 because It may not be compatible with socket.io java client which is version 2.1 from 2022. I have to try.